# Managed resource "azurerm_virtual_network" has not been declared in module

Tags: terraform

A managed resource "azurerm_virtual_network" has not been declared in module

this is the error im getting:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on .terraform\modules\subnet1_app1\network\subnet\main.tf line 5, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet": 

   5:   virtual_network_name                = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name

A managed resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" has not been declared in
module.subnet1_app1.
```

my terraform relevant folder structure is:

```
nonprod
    |_ backend.tf
    |_ outputs.tf
    |_ provider.tf
    |_ resource_groups.tf
    |_ storage.tf
    |_ subnets.tf
    |_ variables.tf
    |_ vnets.tf

modules
|_ resource_group
          |_ outputs.tf
          |_ variables.tf
          |_ main.tf
|_ storage
          |_ outputs.tf
          |_ variables.tf
          |_ main.tf
|_ network
          |_ vnet
                 |_ outputs.tf
                 |_ variables.tf
                 |_ main.tf
          |_ subnet
                 |_ outputs.tf
                 |_ variables.tf
                 |_ main.tf
```

The 2 x RGs and 2 x Vnets do get created if I comment out all Subnet resources, however once I include them again I receive that error message.

I am still quite new to Terraform, any assistance would be appreciated :)

nonprod/resource_groups.tf

```
module "rg_app1" {
  source                    = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/user/my_code/terraform_modules//resource_group"
  rg_name                   = "tf-nonprod"
  rg_location               = "Australia Southeast"
}


module "rg_app2" {
  source                    = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/user/my_code/terraform_modules//resource_group"
  rg_name                   = "tf-nonprod2"
  rg_location               = "Australia Southeast"
}
```

nonprod/vnets.tf

```
module "vnet_app1" {
  source                  = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/user/my_code/terraform_modules//network/vnet"
  vnet_name               = "vnet-app1"
  vnet_location           = module.rg_app1.rg_location
  rg_name                 = module.rg_app1.rg_name
  vnet_address_space      = ["10.100.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers             = ["1.1.1.1","4.4.4.4"]
}

module "vnet_app2" {
  source                  = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/user/my_code/terraform_modules//network/vnet"
  vnet_name               = "vnet-app2"
  vnet_location           = module.rg_app2.rg_location
  rg_name                 = module.rg_app2.rg_name
  vnet_address_space      = ["10.200.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers             = ["1.1.1.1","4.4.4.4"]
}
```

nonprod/subnets.tf

```
  module "subnet1_app1" {
  source                  = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/user/my_code/terraform_modules//network/subnet"    
  subnet_name             = "subnet1"
  rg_name                 = "tf-nonprod"
  vnet_name               =   module.vnet_app1.vnet_name
  vnet_location           = "Australia Southeast"
  subnet_address_prefixes = ["10.100.1.0/24"]
}
```

modules/resource_group/main.tf

```
terraform {
 required_version = ">= 0.12"
}

#create resource group
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name                   = var.rg_name
    location               = var.rg_location
}
```

modules/resource_group/variables.tf

```
variable "rg_location" {
    type          = string
    description   = "location of resource group"
}

variable "rg_name" {
    type          = string
    description   = "name of resource group"
}
```

modules/resource_group/outputs.tf

```
output "rg_location" {
    value         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    description   = "location of resource group"
}

output "rg_name" {
    value         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    description   = "name of resource group"
}
```

modules/network/vnet/main.tf

```
# Create the Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                                = var.vnet_name
  location                            = var.vnet_location
  resource_group_name                 = var.rg_name
  address_space                       = var.vnet_address_space
  dns_servers                         = var.dns_servers
}
```

modules/network/vnet/outputs.tf

```
output "vnet_name" {
  description = "The Name of the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
}

output "vnet_location" {
  description = "The location of the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.location
}

output "vnet_address_space" {
  description = "The address space of the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.address_space
}
```

modules/network/vnet/variables.tf

```
variable "vnet_location" {
  type                = string
  description         = "Location of environment"
}

variable "rg_name" {
    type             = string
    description      = "name of resource group"
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  type               = string
  description        = "Name of Virtual Network"
}

variable "vnet_address_space" {
  type               = list
  description        = "Address space of Virtual Network"
}

variable "dns_servers" {
  type               = list
  description        = "Dns servers for Virtual Network"
}
```

modules/network/subnet/main.tf

```
# Create the Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                                = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name                 = var.rg_name
  virtual_network_name                = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes                    = var.subnet_address_prefixes
}
```

modules/network/subnet/variables.tf

```
variable "rg_name" {
    type             = string
    description      = "name of resource group"
}

variable "subnet_name" {
  type               = string
  description        = "Subnet Name of Virtual Network"
}

variable "subnet_address_prefixes" {
  type               = list
  description        = "Address prefixes of Subnet"
}

# variable "virtual_network_name" {
#   default = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
# }


variable "vnet_location" {
  type                = string
  description         = "Location of environment"
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  type               = string
  description        = "Name of Virtual Network"
}
```

modules/network/subnet/outputs.tf
nothing

Comment: Why did you remove `variable "virtual_network_name"`? You have to pass it to your module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In module.subnet1_app1, i am GUESSING that, this module is being called "modules/network/subnet/main.tf" ...

This line in the module code does not look OK.

```
  virtual_network_name                = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
```

If this was a working module, you have to check if any changes were made to this above line recently...

The value seems to be passed from --> module "subnet1_app1" as below..

```
  vnet_name               =   module.vnet_app1.vnet_name
```

I am no Azure expert, so **GUESSING** that it should have been like below.  Check it out if your terraform plan comes up as expected...

```
  virtual_network_name                = var.vnet_name
```

Comment: Thank you so much giridhar, it worked.  How simple!

Comment: @Cyborganizer : good to know it worked. May be mark it as answer to close this thread.